# If $R/k$ is a ring extension, with $k$ a field, $R$ a integer domain, $[R:k]=n\in\mathbb{N}\implies R$ is a field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

So, $k$ is a subring of $R$, and $\dim_{k}R=n<\infty$. Therefore, for each $a\in R$, we can write

$$a=\sum_{i=i}^{n}a_{i}r_{i}, $$
where $a_{i}\in k\subset R$ and $r_{i}\in R$. How can I prove the existence of $a^{-1}$?

I cannot see how I can use the fact that $R$ is a integer domain. Is there any counter-example if we don't assume $R$ a integer domain?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but here is one: let $0 \neq a \in R$. The map $m_{a} \colon R \to R$ given by left-multiplication by $a$ is $k$-linear. It is also injective because $R$ is an integral domain. Can you see why $m_{a}$ must also be surjective, and why this answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=ax$ is linear and injective, since $R$ is an integral domain, it is bijective since injective maps between finite dimensional vector spaces are   invertible, there exists $b$ such that $f(b)=ax=1$